# radial-gradient CSS origin on the top, not in the center

Tags: css, sass, gradient, radial-gradients

I'm playing around with radial gradients and I cannot get to have the effect I wish.

I'm tried using the [colorzilla gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) but they center the gradient always in the middle. I've tried by my own transform it but I do not know if there is an option to change the origin of the gradient. I would like the origin to be in the middle horizontally but at the top vertically.

I've tried the following with no success:

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover at 50% 0px, $center 0%,$outer 70%);
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, $center 0%,$outer 70%);
```

Below is the effect I'm trying to emulate:

[image]

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3z4t3tsv/)? I think your syntax/order of values is incorrect.

Comment: @Harry Yes, something like this! where do you decide the origin of the radial gradient? I want to understand the radial gradient property.

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient ♦ http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#radial-gradients

Comment: @DanielRamirez-Escudero: The `50% 0%` is the one where it is specified in format `x-axis-pos y-axis-pos`. *Note:* The standard `radial-gradient` syntax is a bit different from the `-webkit-` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank to Harry I found the answer. If this helps anybody here is what I used to get this gradient effect, it seems to work on all browsers except IE9 of course...

```
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50%, 0, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(70%,#b7b7b7));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use a radial gradient first you set gradient shape - in example circle, next is a position - center top, finally you set colours. You can use this example and change it, of course you must write missing syntax for all browsers.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.example {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffffff;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center top, #ffffff 0%, #f1f1f1 50%, #e1e1e1 55%, #f6f6f6 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="example"></div>
```